# Not able to find pattern in data sample

Tags: java, logic

I'm seeking help with the logic and not the technology to solve this problem. I was writing a program in Java to use categorized data(consisting temperature and blood pressure mapped to a state of Infected/NotInfected/unknown) and classify a given set of travelers as
“Infected”, “NotInfected” or “Unknown” accordingly.

**Input:**
The input comprises of a string containing two parts separated by ‘#’. The first part contains
categorized data for any number of individuals separated by comma. Data for each individual
contains space separated three values as follows:

Temperature bloodpressure category

The second part contains space separated temperature and blood pressure of multiple travelers
separated by comma.

**Output:**
Categorization of travelers separated by comma.

**Sample Input & Output**

```
90 120 Infected,90 150 NotInfected,100 140 Infected,80 130 NotInfected#95 125,95 145,75 160   | Output:    Infected,Unknown,NotInfected
80 120 Infected,70 145 Infected,90 100 Infected,80 150 NotInfected,80 80 NotInfected,100 120 NotInfected#120 148,75 148,60 90 | Output: NotInfected,Unknown,Unknown
```

I went on to solve this by splitting the strings provided in to substring one containing the categorized data and the other containing the input data set.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="90 120 Infected, 90 150 NotInfected, 100 140 NotInfected, 80 130 NotInfected#95 125, 95 145, 75 160";
    String categories = s.split("#")[0];
    String inputs = s.split("#")[1];
    System.out.println(categories+"\n"+inputs);

    for (String input: inputs.split(",")){
      //iterate through categories and match against input 
    }

}
```

But I realized that I was not able to find any pattern that could help me get the desired output as mentioned in the "Sample above". Which type of temperature-BP leads to Infected category?

Comment: what is the logic of your output ?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve that output. The logic is what I have to find.

Answer (score 0):

So, your problem is to learn a classifier from your sample (training data) and then be able to classify new cases (described by explanatory variables, temperature and blood pressure) into one of three classes.

There are numerous ways to learn classifiers, but first you should find out, if your explanatory variables actually explain the classes (i.e. if there is a pattern). For this purpose, I would suggest a simple check: plot you training data in two dimensions (explanatory variables) and give each of the three classes a different symbol (e.g. letter N, I, U). You will see if all classes are randomly mixed or if the same symbols tend to aggregate together. Or are you able to draw lines that separate different classes sufficiently well? You don't need to be able to  separate classes perfectly - some classification errors just belong to life - but your should be able to see some tendency.

If there is a clear class division, then you should just select a classifier to learn. Learning algorithms are widely available, so you don't need to code it yourself. You could try e.g. classification trees (classical c4.5 learning algorithm). Or if your training set is sufficiently large, you could use a K-nearest neighbour classifier that doesn't require any learning phase: you simply classify a new case according to its K nearest neighbours in the training data (you can just calculate Euclidean distances between points in the temperature and blood pressure space, select K points with shortest distances from you new query point and select the most common class among neighbours).